# Pie Chart Legend - Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart, legend-properties

I need help to put the number of the pie chart in the legend

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grBpc.png)

If i hover the chart with mouse i can see the number relative to each item

i want to display it in the legend either

the important code so far:

```
var tempData = {
    labels: Status,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Status",
            data: Qtd,
            backgroundColor: randColor
        },

    ]
};

var ctx = $("#pieStatus").get(0).getContext("2d");
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: tempData,
    options: {
         title: {
            display: true,
            fontsize: 14,
            text: 'Total de Pedidos por Situação'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',

        },
        responsive: false
    }

});
```

> "Qtd","randColor" are "var" already with values

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to edit the `generateLabels` property in your options :

```
options: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            generateLabels: function(chart) {
                 // Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Since it is quite a mess to create on your own a great template. I suggest using the same function as in [the source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/controllers/controller.doughnut.js#L42-L69) and then edit what is needed.

Here are a [small jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bexkyd9/), where you can see how it works (*edited lines - from 38 - are commented*), and its result :

[image]

Comment: in fiddler you are showing Mouse hover tool-tip has also changed, which i didn't found where is it in your code?

Comment: @UzairXlade I haven't touched the tooltip in the fiddler. Tooltips are automatically defined with the labels set in the data (in the first lines)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is a hacky solution, but for me seems simpler.

### The `filter` parameter

[ChartJS legend options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) have a `filter` parameter. This is a function that is called for each legend item, and that returns true/false whether you want to show this item in the legend or not.

`filter` has 2 arguments:

- `legendItem` : The legend item to show/omit. Its properties are described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface)
- `data` : The data object passed to the chart.

### The hack

Since JS passes objects by reference, and `filter` is called for each legend item, then you can mutate the `legendItem` object to show the text that you want.

```js
legend : {
  labels: {
    filter: (legendItem, data) => {
      // First, retrieve the data corresponding to that label
      const label = legendItem.text
      const labelIndex = _.findIndex(data.labels, (labelName) => labelName === label) // I'm using lodash here
      const qtd = data.datasets[0].data[labelIndex]
      
      // Second, mutate the legendItem to include the new text
      legendItem.text = `${legendItem.text} : ${qtd}`
      
      // Third, the filter method expects a bool, so return true to show the modified legendItem in the legend
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from tektiv's answer, I've modified it for ES6 which my linter requires;

```js
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      generateLabels: (chart) => {
        const { data } = chart;
        if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
          return data.labels.map((label, i) => {
            const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            const ds = data.datasets[0];
            const arc = meta.data[i];
            const custom = (arc && arc.custom) || {};
            const { getValueAtIndexOrDefault } = Chart.helpers;
            const arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;
            const fill = custom.backgroundColor ? custom.backgroundColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.backgroundColor, i, arcOpts.backgroundColor);
            const stroke = custom.borderColor ? custom.borderColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderColor, i, arcOpts.borderColor);
            const bw = custom.borderWidth ? custom.borderWidth : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderWidth, i, arcOpts.borderWidth);
            const value = chart.config.data.datasets[arc._datasetIndex].data[arc._index];

            return {
              text: `${label}: ${value}`,
              fillStyle: fill,
              strokeStyle: stroke,
              lineWidth: bw,
              hidden: Number.isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
              index: i,
            };
          });
        }
        return [];
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let the user select from 100+ data sets, but rather than adding/removing them from my *Chart* I decided to set the `showLine: false` on any dataset that I want hidden. Unfortunately the default *legend* would show all 100+. So in my solution I generate the legend manually, filtering out any dataset that has `showLine: false`.

Your settings will have this:

```
legend: {
  labels: {
    generateLabels: (a) => {
      return a.data.labels
    }
  }
```

And you'll generate your own labels with a helper function:

```
function updateAllLabels() {
  const myNewLabels = [];

  myChart.data.datasets.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.showLine) {
      myNewLabels.push(generateLabel(element));
    }
  });

  myChart.data.labels = myNewLabels;
}
```

And you'll generate the label with another function:

```
function generateLabel(data) {
  return {
    fillStyle: data.borderColor,
    lineWidth: 1,
    strokeStyle: data.borderColor,
    text: data.countyName, // I attach countryName to my datasets for convenience
  }
}
```

Now just don't forget to call the function whenever updating your chart:

```
updateAllLabels();
myChart.update();
```

Happy graphing!