# ChartJS different border color for legend

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, pie-chart, react-chartjs

I need to set a different border color for the legend than the actual chart; whenever I add border color to the chart data, it gets applied to both legend and chart. And I couldn't find any options for setting different border colors for the legend [in documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve, any idea?:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found to do this and some other customisation on the legend is to implement the [legend item interface](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html).

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454586/pie-chart-legend-chart-js) in combination with the legend item interface should be a good start.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4sqt6oL/34/) that I made from that answer, but updated for chartjs 3.7.1. The main part to focus on is this:

```
options: {
plugins: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,

      generateLabels: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.data;
        if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
          return data.labels.map(function(label, i) {
          
            var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            var ds = data.datasets[0];
            return {
              text: label,
              fillStyle: ds.backgroundColor[i],
              strokeStyle: ds.legendOutline[i],
              lineWidth: ds.borderWidth,
              hidden: isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
              index: i
            };
          });
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

strokeStyle is the outline property, and I've made a field in the dataset called legendOutline. legendOutline and the data from the dataset are both referenced with i, so the legendOutline[i] points to the label representing data[i]